# TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object IN Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am getting this error while setting up app on my localhost. "Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object".
 Please take a look to solve this problem.

```
../master/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a
            ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (/home/divine20/master/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/divine20/master/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:219:21)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at EventEmitter.use (/home/divine20/master/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:216:7)
    at Object.exports.default (/home/divine20/master/server/routes.js:25:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/divine20/master/server/app.js:34:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

My app.js File.

```
 'use strict';

 import express from 'express';
 import mongoose from 'mongoose';
 mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
 import config from './config/environment';
 import http from 'http';

 // Connect to MongoDB
 mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);
 mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
     console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err);
     process.exit(-1);
 });

 // Populate databases with sample data
 if (config.seedDB) {
     require('./config/seed');
 }

 // Setup server
 var app = express();
 var server = http.createServer(app);
 var socketio = require('socket.io')(server, {
     serveClient: config.env !== 'production',
     path: '/socket.io-client'
 });
 require('./config/socketio').default(socketio);
 require('./config/express').default(app);
 require('./routes').default(app);

 // Start server
 function startServer() {
     app.angularFullstack = server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function() {
         console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
     });
 }

 setImmediate(startServer);

 // Expose app
 exports = module.exports = app;
```

**my routes.js file.**

```
'use strict';

import errors from './components/errors';
import path from 'path';
import aws from './api/config/aws.js';

export default function(app) {
    // Insert routes below
    app.use('/api/reports', require('./api/report'));
    app.use('/api/utilities', require('./api/utility'));
    app.use('/api/mails', require('./api/mail'));
    app.use('/api/repayments', require('./api/repayment'));
    app.use('/api/transactions', require('./api/transaction'));
    app.use('/api/offers', require('./api/offer'));
    app.use('/api/payments', require('./api/payment'));
    app.use('/api/yelp', require('./api/yelp'));
    app.use('/api/blogs', require('./api/blog'));
    app.use('/api/faqs', require('./api/faq'));
    app.use('/api/blog', require('./api/blog'));
    app.use('/api/listings', require('./api/listing'));
    app.use('/api/users', require('./api/user'));
    app.get('/api/s3Policy', aws.getS3Policy);
    app.post('/api/uploadToS3', aws.uploadToS3);

    app.use('/auth', require('./auth'));

    // All undefined asset or api routes should return a 404
    app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
        .get(errors[404]);

    // All other routes should redirect to the index.html
    app.route('/*')
        .get((req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
        });
}
```

There is an Index.js under auth folder where **express.Router()** has been used.

```
'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import config from '../config/environment';
import User from '../api/user/user.model';

// Passport Configuration
require('./local/passport').setup(User, config);
require('./facebook/passport').setup(User, config);
require('./google/passport').setup(User, config);

var router = express.Router();

router.use('/local', require('./local'));
router.use('/facebook', require('./facebook'));
router.use('/google', require('./google'));

export default router;
```

Comment: Did you try replacing `app.use('/auth', require('./auth'));` with `app.use('/auth', require('./auth').default);` ?

Comment: Still same error..:(

Comment: May be it's issue with `export` scope. Can you replace it with `module.exports=router`?

Comment: Did you try logging with `console.log(require('./auth'))` to see what it contains?

Comment: nothing  change when i trying logging console.log(require('./auth')). 
Error  as it is.

Comment: Add make sure you export a middleware function in `auth.js`

Comment: yes. 
"var router = express.Router();
export default router;"

Comment: add `module.exports=router` in auth???